# Migrate from Legacy jQuery plugin to Bootstrap+Typeahead or jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, typeahead.js

**background:**

We have a legacy system running the now dead [Autocomplete plugin for jquery](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/). We use it in multiple places on an intranet web UI. Until recently the client ran IE6 (*yes, I know...*) and this was all fairly static.

We're going to rededevelop the old front end of the UI. At the moment I'm considering using either jQuery UI or Bootstrap + Typeahead.

**question:**

The fields we use the autocomplete functionality often chain the values of other fields (themselves using autocompleted), passing these values as additional paramaters to our back end script. Is there an easy way to include these with the twitter bootstrap/typeahead method as there is with jQuery-UI?

If it's not too rude an example of each using additional parameters would be amazing.

Thanks in advance

**edit:**

I'm asking because I think bootstrap is smaller/lighter and less work to generate a nice UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using the Kendo UI Web (Free Version) autocomplete along with Bootstrap 3 and it is working very well.

The look is not like the other form elements generated by Bootstrap due to KendoUI CSS, but that seems minor.

We are also using MVVM pattern and Kendo Observables (Similary to Knockout) which makes it very easy to pass parameters to the backend systems.